# Custom navigation in slick.js slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I want to have a navigation like this:

```
<div style="margin-top:122px; display: flex; justify-content: space-between; width:124px">
    <a href="#">01.</a>
    <a href="#">02.</a>
    <a href="#">03.</a>
</div>
```

01.
        02.
        03.

When I click on one of the anchors I want to show slide with than index. I already implemented `nextArrow` and `prevArrow`. But I don't see in documentation any method like `setIndex` or something.

How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation on the slick-slider demo page](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), there is a method called `slickGoTo` that takes the index of the slide you want to show.

Comment: No need to use that method.slickNext and slickPrev are provided in there too.For dots use the above method